# PHP Cannot properly parse JSON

Tags: php, json

**EDIT:** Pasting the code in Stack Overflow make it works. SO renders the mysterious tab glyph into spacebar. With the tab glyph, JSON does not work properly. More information could be found below on my comment.

---

I have this list of JSON:

```
[{"title": "<U><b>01420111</U></b> General Physics I","locations": "หมู่ 1 ห้อง PHYS 101<br>กุลพันธ์    <br> เวลา: 11:00-12:30","start": 240, "end": 330, "color": "#009688"},{"title": "<U><b>01417167</U></b> Engineering Mathematics I","locations": "หมู่ 1 ห้อง LH 3-304<br>ชาญ,กนกรัตน์   <br> เวลา: 13:00-14:30","start": 360, "end": 450, "color": "#00bcd4"}]
```

which, for the purpose of reading, could be indented to this

```
[
  {
    "title": "<U><b>01420111</U></b> General Physics I",
    "locations": "หมู่ 1 ห้อง PHYS 101<br>กุลพันธ์  <br> เวลา: 11:00-12:30",
    "start": 240,
    "end": 330,
    "color": "#009688"
  },
  {
    "title": "<U><b>01417167</U></b> Engineering Mathematics I",
    "locations": "หมู่ 1 ห้อง LH 3-304<br>ชาญ,กนกรัตน์  <br> เวลา: 13:00-14:30",
    "start": 360,
    "end": 450,
    "color": "#00bcd4"
  }
]
```

After I did tried parsing the JSON, which [could be tried online here](http://php.fnlist.com/php/json_decode), seems the `JSON_decode()` function returns null instead of expected array.

Any suggestions on the JSON syntax, and also the solution to "fix" the syntax, making PHP decoding it properly? Thanks in advance~

Comment: The site you linked to shows that `json_decode` is successful with the json text you posted. What code gives you `null` instead of the expected array?

Comment: It should be `json_decode()` not `JSON_decode()` the function is case sensitive.

Comment: More details has been added. SO changes the whitespace to glyph, making it parsable by PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is valid, and `json_decode` works just fine. Check out [this demo](https://3v4l.org/h7qj5).

The site you linked to shows the same result.  You are probably applying `json_decode` to non-JSON text, or you're mistyping the function name (`json_decode` is case-sensitive, so `JSON_decode` will fail).  Here is how to error check with json:

```
$json_string = '...';
$parsed = json_decode($json_string);  // <- not JSON_decode

//check for error and handle it however makes sense
if(json_last_error()) die(json_last_error_msg());

//safe to continue. parsing successful
```

Comment: Thank you. More details has been added. SO changes the whitespace to glyph, making it parsable by PHP, rendering the JSON in usable status.

Comment: @srakrn my answer shows you how to find out the specific error

Comment: Thank you, `Syntax error` thrown. As I have expected, it was JSON's syntax, which I still need further help explained in the next comment. Thank your for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, now I realise the fault, it is at the whitespace in the JSON.

Stack Overflow seems to replace the mysterious glyph in JSON with normal spacebar, making the JSON valid for parsing. [However, the original JSON, which contains the mysterious glyph, now pasted on Pastebin to preserve its glyph](http://pastebin.com/TpgJhHvJ), could not be parsed.

Observe the space behind "กุลพันธ์" *in raw paste data*. The glyph is different from normal spacebar.

The next questions are 1) How can I know which glyph is that, and 2) How can I replace it with normal space in PHP?

Thanks for all of your willing to help again!